# how can i change the date format in javascript <tr><td> tag

Tags: date, input, tags

i'm making PERN-TODO-APP using javascript, postgresql DB, nodejs etc.
and i use  tag and when i add (post function to the postgresql) date type data to the
html, i can see the below format

2022-07-07T15:00:00.000Z <<

how can i change the 'date' format? when i add in the  tag.. inside html
or should i change the browser option? either no matter..

below the code, (i just make code simple to be easily understood)

ListTodo.js

```
          </tr> */}
          {todos.map(todo => (
            <tr key={todo.todo_id}>
              <td>{todo.description}</td>
              <td>{todo.description2}</td>
              <td>{todo.date_visit}</td>
              <td>{todo.visitor_name}</td>
              <td>
                <EditTodo todo={todo} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.todo_id)}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ListTodos;
```

inputtodo.js

```
        <div id="라벨">방문날짜 : </div>
        <input
          type="date"
          className="form-control"
          value={date_visit}
          onChange={e => setdate_visit(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) if that is the output string you after. Else there are other [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to choose from.

Comment: i wonder <td>{todo.date_visit}</td> << how can i make this "date type" to format "YYYY-MM-DD" not "2022-07-07T15:00:00.000Z" type..? i don't know how can i use toDatestring function. :(

Comment: Then I would use the toLocaleDateString function. So something like this.

<td>{new Date(todo.date_visit).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')}</td>

// 2022-07-13 (year-month-day)


Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString